# Export json to excel

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, export-to-excel

**Context**:
I have a search page which retrieves data from one database table and I display it like a pivot table using a bunch of jquery plugins and some written code.

**What I want to do**: export both sources to excel, the original data and the treated to be pivot like.

**Some code**:

```
$('#btn-apply').click(function() {
  params = buildParams(); //-> json object structure

    $.ajax({
        url: '<%= pivot_apply_path%>',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        data: params,
        success: function(result) {
            json.source = $.parseJSON(result); //-> original json response and data from acctiverecord
            json.pivot = pivot(json.source.data, params.rows, params.columns, {}); //-> treated data to another json
            html = tableGeneration(json.pivot); //-> generate a table from the treated json and show it
        }
    });
});
```

This all works great, but now the **challenge**:

1. Click a button, send the source json, and retrieve and excel with this data
2. Click a button, send the pivot json, and retrieve and excel with this data

What I did:

1. Pass both the source json to the controller and received like this

> def export_table
>
> ```
> @records = params
>
> respond_to do |format|
>     format.xls
> end
> ```
>
> end

I already have a view export_source.xls.erb which is the technique I used before to export a xls, all the formatting works fine. The problem is the response to the json call...

```
$('.export-table').click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<%= pivot_export_table_path%>',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xls",
            data: { data: json.pivot },
            success: function(result) {
                //<-  
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                showMessage('error', error); //<- ENDS UP HERE  
            }
        });
});
```

As this is not a postback link so it doesn't postback my xls, worse, it doesn't even enter my ajax success, it goes directly to error with the description `No conversion from text to xls`

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This discussion with slicedpan left me thinking on one solution:

1. Make a form on my view with an input text hidden
2. Submit my form in a simple Post (no ajax)
3. On the click of the button (before the post) put the json stringified on the input
4. Read it on the controller with `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(value)` side and render the format.xls as always

Just tested it, and works ok, pitty this solution is not so pretty...I will still leave this open for someone to come up with a nicer one.

Right on!

Answer (score 1):

JQuery doesn't support 'xls' as a data type. I think you can just replace 'xls' with 'text' and it will work fine, jquery doesn't need to understand the xls format.

After a little bit of reading, it seems the only way to do this is to dynamically create a form in the click handler, then submit it. You need to json encode the data and then submit it in a hidden field. Something like this should work

```
$('.export-table').click(function(e) {
  var form_el = $('<form action="<%= pivot_export_table_path%>" method="POST"></form>');
  $('body').append(form_el);
  form_el.append($('<%= token_tag %>');  //if you are using CSRF protection

  var obj = {thing: "sdfjk", things: [1,4,6,6]};

  var input_el = $('<input type="hidden" name="json_data"></input>');
  form_el.append(input_el);
  input_el.val(JSON.stringify(obj));

  form_el.submit();

});
```

Then in your controller, you need to use

```
@records = JSON.parse(params[:json_data])
```

Comment: Sure, if I replace 'xls' by text, or delete it, I get into the success routine, still doesn't download the excel I expect. The 'result' is the excel content to string...

Comment: Download the excel :)

Comment: oh right, you don't need to use ajax in that case, you can just put in a link to a url that maps to the correct controller action (set the disposition to attachment also if you don't want the browser to try and render it)

Comment: You can dynamically change the href attribute of a link when you click it, but I see you're using POST so that won't work. Let me try an experiment

Comment: How did you get the xls file to download before?

Comment: ie: `<%= link_to 'Export', tables_exportXLS_path(format: "xls"), { :method => 'POST' } %>` no json required, no problem...

Answer (score -1):

You can use a JSON to EXCEL converter available [here](https://bitbucket.org/kylo_ren/big_data_json_to_excel_converter/src)

Comment: That is a dead link and you should provide your answer here because of situations like this.

Comment: Go to user name kylo_ren on bitbucket and you'll find it. Sorry for dead link.